# Sql command that shows the cost greater than

Tags: sql, database

I have 3 tables

```
CREATE TABLE Hotell 
(
    hotelNum int primary key,
    hotelName varchar(50),
    city varchar(50)
)

CREATE TABLE Roomm
(
    roomNum int primary key,
    hotelNum int ,
    type varchar(50),
    price int 
)

CREATE TABLE Bookingg 
(
    hotelNum int,
    guestNum int primary key,
    dateFrom int,
    dateTo int,
    roomNum int
)
```

I need to list the guests who stay at hotels costing more than 250 per night, and I also want to include the hotel name and city in my screen

Comment: We are here to help you. But you have to explain your difficulties. This is the reason your question was downvoted for now.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this could help you

```
Select 
    A.guestNum,B.hotelName,C.price
From
    Bookingg as [A] Inner Join Hotell as [B] On A.hotelNum = B.hotelNum
    Inner join Roomm as [C] B.hotelNum = C.hotelNum
Where 
    C.price > 250
```